# Mounting a USB digital camera on Gentoo

Tags: usb, camera, gentoo

I'm having trouble mounting my Kodak EasyShare C190 under gentoo. It seems to be getting recognized without issue, but as far as I can tell is not assigned a device-name with which to mount it:

lsusb finds it:
`Bus 006 Device 007: ID 040a:05d9 Kodak Co.`

/var/log/messages seems to indicate no problems:

```
Aug 27 17:53:42 human kernel: [ 1424.463074] usb 6-2: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 8
Aug 27 17:53:42 human kernel: [ 1424.602180] usb 6-2: default language 0x0409
Aug 27 17:53:42 human kernel: [ 1424.618209] usb 6-2: udev 8, busnum 6, minor = 647
Aug 27 17:53:42 human kernel: [ 1424.618213] usb 6-2: New USB device found, idVendor=040a, idProduct=05d9
Aug 27 17:53:42 human kernel: [ 1424.618217] usb 6-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Aug 27 17:53:42 human kernel: [ 1424.618221] usb 6-2: Product: KODAK EASYSHARE C190 Digital Camera
Aug 27 17:53:42 human kernel: [ 1424.618224] usb 6-2: Manufacturer: Eastman Kodak Company
Aug 27 17:53:42 human kernel: [ 1424.618226] usb 6-2: SerialNumber: KCTLH93610158
Aug 27 17:53:42 human kernel: [ 1424.618308] usb 6-2: uevent
Aug 27 17:53:42 human kernel: [ 1424.618331] usb 6-2: usb_probe_device
Aug 27 17:53:42 human kernel: [ 1424.618333] usb 6-2: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Aug 27 17:53:42 human kernel: [ 1424.619366] usb 6-2: uevent
Aug 27 17:53:42 human kernel: [ 1424.620181] usb 6-2: adding 6-2:1.0 (config #1, interface 0)
Aug 27 17:53:42 human kernel: [ 1424.620195] usb 6-2:1.0: uevent
Aug 27 17:53:42 human kernel: [ 1424.620235] drivers/usb/core/inode.c: creating file '008'
```

It's listed under /proc/bus/usb/devices:

```
T:  Bus=06 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  9 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=040a ProdID=05d9 Rev= 1.00
S:  Manufacturer=Eastman Kodak Company
S:  Product=KODAK EASYSHARE C190 Digital Camera
S:  SerialNumber=KCTLH93610158
C:* #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=  2mA
I:* If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=06(still) Sub=01 Prot=01 Driver=(none)
E:  Ad=01(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=82(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   8 Ivl=16ms
```

I've tried mountind /dev/sdb1 through /dev/sdg1 (other external devices are typically mapped to sdb) with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the setting you have (or had) for `CAMERAS` in `/etc/make.conf`?

Comment: there's a camera setting in /etc/make.conf? (in answer to your question, none)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the camera is not identifying itself as a Mass Storage Device, that's what the logs tell me.

You can try using:

- fdisk to list all partitions to confirm it is not mounted `sudo fdisk -l`
- Use a software like digiKam or other digital camera management software to see if software recognizes the camera
- Check the camera settings to see if it is in PICT bridge mode. If so try setting it to Mass storage device mode

Comment: DigiKam relies on libgphoto2 to interface with cameras, I believe. I guess I just assumed the OP had it already installed, but that's a good idea, definitely worth checking. +1

Comment: The camera settings don't have any kind of bridge mode settigns... they're actually quite sparse and only have to do with picture settings, clock and so on. fdisk -l confirms it is not mounted. Do you have any equivalents to digiKam? Installing it requires some heavy changes to my use flags and about a hundred megs worth of KDE dependencies

Comment: I found that "gphoto2" also uses libgphoto2 - In using that I got the following error: "*** Error ***              
Could not detect any camera
*** Error (-105: 'Unknown model') ***   "

Comment: gThumb seems to work, actually, so thank you, I now have my photos :) Do you know of a way to make the camera act as a Mass Storage Device, assuming I cannot find anything like that in the menus?

Comment: @Mala glad hear, I suggested digiKam since I didn't know what was the Gnome/GTK equivalent of a camera management tool. As for switching to Mass storage device, I'll have to search a bit. Will update if I get anything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure someone will come along with a better answer, but as a quick hack, I'd try `ls /dev`, then plug the camera in, then `ls /dev` again and see if anything new appears.

Alternatively, try doing the same thing with the command `ls /dev/disk/*`.

If you don't find anything, you may have to tweak your udev rules, which I don't know much about so I'll leave that for someone else to explain.

Comment: sadly there is no difference whatsoever. I piped the ls output to files each time and `diff` claimed they were identical